# Can't publish ASP.Net Razor app because of locked file in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have an ASP.Net Razor web site that I've been enhancing and successfully publishing to our intranet for the last couple of years. I recently started using VS2017 with it without any problems. Today, I encountered an error when I tried to publish it:

```
Error       Copying file .vs\ETF\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock to C:\Users\myId\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\mySite-1436350714\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\.vs\ETF\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock failed. The process cannot access the file '.vs\ETF\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock' because it is being used by another process.
```

I tried restarting my machine and renaming *db.lock* in the .vs\ETF\v15\Server\sqlite3 folder, but when I start the project in VS and try to publish it again, it recreates *db.lock* file (with current timestamp), and gives me the same error. I use SQL Server in the app, but have no idea where the *sqlite3* reference is coming from. Also there is no *db.lock* file in the destination directory.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as my online searches have been fruitless.

Comment: You shouldn't be publishing `.vs/` at all.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not. Never have.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this exact problem after updating to Visual Studio 2017 Community from Visual Studio 2015 Pro.  I also changed PCs in the upgrade.  I found the solution to be the .vs folder wasn't hidden.  Change the attribute hidden for the entire folder and subfolders and that should fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got a response over on MSDN and they told me to just delete the .vs folder altogether, which also solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add this line in your publish profile (blabla.pubxml file):

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

Like the following:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, simply uncheck the "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option in your publish profile settings. Then I shutdown VS and deleted the .VS/project name folder. Started VS back up and published the web app.